# Drupal7 - User/Registration Customizing

Tags: php, drupal, user-profile

Please any one help me to how I can do customizing User/Registration page in Drupal7. For ex I have a select option for user group suppose if I choose 'others' option ’ then user is allowed to create new group in separate text box.

I'm new to drupal. Please anyone help me

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom module and use [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7).

You can then modify the form by adding [drupal form elements](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7).

```
function custom_module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id === 'user_register_form') {
    $form['account']['other'] = array(
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#title' => t('Other'),
      '#options' => array(
        0 => t('No'),
        1 => t('Yes'),
      ),
    );
    $form['account']['group'] = array(
      '#type' => 'text_format',
      '#title' => t('Group'),
      '#default_value' => '',
      '#format' => NULL,
    );
  }
}
```